# 1 to 2 mb XML file in MSSQL or Filesystem / Size based storing criteria for XML files

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have xml files which I am trying to decide whether to save on **Filesystem** or **SQL** the file size varies from 1MB to 2MB. Can sql handle a single record of such size? Also can anyone  make a guide of Filesystem vs Sql based purely on datasize when deciding on storage of XML data like the following.

```
Datasize       IdealStorage
0 to 100kb     SQL
100kb to 1MB   Filesystem/ other methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends , how many XML files you want to store , 100 ? 1000 ? or 10000000 ?

but IMO, File system will be best.

```
 Can sql handle a single record of such size?
```

Yes, Sql server can handle, there is no problem at all , but the real question is how efficiently sql can handle .. ?

```
Filesystem vs Sql
```

I will say
- if the file size is less then 1 MB, go for Sql Server storage
- If more then 2 MB, choose File System

I have answered same sort of question , you can read more about here

You can read more this [What are the different possibilities to store a large number of files in a SQL Server 2008 Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442690/what-are-the-different-possibilities-to-store-a-large-number-of-files-in-a-sql-s/17443494#17443494)

Hope it will help

Comment: The files are personal information for user only. Currently I have 100 users but I expect it to exceed 10000 records.

Comment: Then I can not see any issue to store them inside Sql as well ... you may consider varbinary datatype or XML column. The XML data type was first introduced with SQL Server 2005. Most notably is the power of the XQuery language to analyze and query the values contained in your XML instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. 2 Mb shouldn't be a problem. I think the max limit for binary is 2 GB. Not sure, can check references on MSDN. Filestream or BLOB storage is also one option if you are dealing in huge files.
2. The guide which you are requesting is not the solution because there will be many differing school of thoughts there. A guide just based on size may not be.
3. A few pointers here for your reference. Bit old, but relevant:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/13/sql-server-blob-pointer-to-image-image-in-database-filestream-storage/

[SQL Server Express database size / BLOB storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560443/sql-server-express-database-size-blob-storage)

Comment: You should know that there is a known defect in SQL Server 2008 R2 (and likely other versions) that fails snapshots when an XML field is > 1 MB. If your database requires replication, you may want to look at alternatives such as filesystem. Of course if you need to replicate the filesystem you have additional issues to contend with.

Comment: @OskarAustegard Thanks for the info. Any source where I can learn about this problem? I suppose your comment was supposed for the answer above? Because I was not talking about XML columns here, only binary. However, XML columns would be a best-fit for moderately sized XML.

Comment: Belated answer for @abhitalks: sorry, no, this is empirical information gathered from our own use case and confirmed by a MS support person